# (C) avcodec_receive_frame (ffmpeg) function always returns AVERROR(EAGAIN)

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, media-player, decoding

I was following this tutorial: http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html
and was trying to change some deprecated functions, and so I had to try to use the `avcodec_send_packet` and `avcodec_receive_frame` functions.

The problem I'm having is that `avcodec_receive_frame` always returns `AVERROR(EAGAIN)`.

My decoding function is as follows:

```
static int decode(AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx, AVFrame *pFrame, AVPacket *packet) {
    
    int ret = avcodec_send_packet(pCodecCtx, packet);
    if (ret<0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error sending packet for decoding\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (ret>=0) {        
        // avcodec_receive_packet(pCodecCtx, NULL);
        ret = avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecCtx, pFrame);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\naverror(eagain) ret = %d\n", ret);
            return -1;
        }
        else if (ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
            fprintf(stderr, "eof\n");
            return -100;
        }
        else if (ret <0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error during decoding\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Everywhere I read said that this is solved by calling `avcodec_send_packet` with the next frame, but this does not solve the problem for me because this function is being called in a loop:

```
    while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0) {
        // is this a packet from the video stream?
        if (packet.stream_index==videoStream) {

           frameNotFinished = decode(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &packet);

            // did we get a video frame?
            if (!frameNotFinished) fprintf(stderr, "it worked!");
        }
        av_packet_unref(&packet);   
    }
```

I should probably also add that `avcodec_send_packet` always returns 0 (success).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just keep calling send_packet until receive_frame returns 0. It could take up to 16 frames (or more depending on the codec)

Comment: What does EAGAIN error mean? use `continue` instead of `return` in the `if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN))` condition check.

Comment: @madD7 if I do that the `decode` function will return with success, which is not what should happen

Comment: @szatmary I'm calling it for all frames in a small video (that has way more than 16 frames) in the loop and still it always returns -11 (AVERROR(EAGAIN))

Comment: You're using `avcodec_send_packet` and `avcodec_read_frame`. The tutorial uses `av_read_frame`. There is an `avcodec_send_frame`. From: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.4/group__lavc__decoding.html and links to the functions, I'm wondering if you have to be consistent with using either `*_packet` or `*_frame` but _not_ intermixing them?

Comment: @CraigEstey the `av_read_frame` is going to "return" a packet, and the packet needs to be input into the `avcodec_send_packet`, so I cannot use `avcodec_send_frame` (which does not accept a packet). I think this last function is used to encode frames, while I'm trying to do the opposite. (I still mix a lot of this up but I believe I'm saying the right thing)

Comment: I've got commercial product experience with realtime broadcast quality H.264 encoders/decoders [in particular with the data pipelines], but I'm not so familiar with setting one up with `ffmpeg`. But ... If you _send_ packets in, you may need to receive _packets_ out. Or ... If you send in a single packet, you [probably] don't have enough data to get a _frame_ out [hence, the receive frame returns `EAGAIN`]. You may have keep feeding packets, and, _eventually_ enough has gone in that you can get a _frame_ out. So, you may have to decouple the send and receive code ...

Comment: As your code exists now, you expect that a single packet in will produce a frame out. You may need something like [loosely]: `while (1) { read_packet_from_file(fdin,packet); avcodec_send_packet(ctx,packet);  ret = avcodec_receive_frame(ctx,frame); if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN)) continue;  write_frame_to_file(fdout,frame); }`

Comment: There are _multiple_ functions that `avcode_read_frame` invokes that can return `EAGAIN`--the code internally checks for that in many places. You may need to install the debug symbols for `libffmpeg` or recompile from source with `-g`. Then, you can run your program under `gdb` using breakpoints and single stepping to find the exact line of code that first sets `EAGAIN`

Comment: Now, _I_ may be confused. But, from: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/group__lavc__encdec.html we have  [for the return value from `avcode_receive_frame`]: _0: success, **a frame was returned AVERROR(EAGAIN): output is not available in this state - user must try to send new input** AVERROR_EOF: the decoder has been fully flushed, and there will be no more output frames AVERROR(EINVAL): codec not opened, or it is an encoder other negative values: legitimate decoding errors_

Comment: @CraigEstey if I understand correctly what you are saying, then that is what I'm doing... my `decode` function is called with a new packet (from `av_read_frame`) every time; then it goes into the `avcodec_send_packet`; then the `avcodec_receive_frame` "checks" if it is ready or not; if not (which is what always happens here for some reason), then this function returns -1 and the loop starts again (another packet is read and `decode` is called again, etc). I believe this should be the same as what you suggested

Answer (score 0):

You never return when you actually get a frame (ret == 0)

From the other hand, if you return you will not actually 'decode' all the frames until you get AVERROR(EAGAIN) which means that you might lose some frames. So, I guess you first have to decide what you exactly want to do.

(I guess you just need to have your "process" function within the while (ret>=0) and if you have ret == 0 you do whatever you do)

The process is the following....

1. You demux a packet [av_read_frame]
2. If it's an X video stream packet you send it to the decoder [avcodec_send_packet]
3. You try to decode and receive all available AVFrames (if any) [avcodec_receive_frame]

3.1) If no frames are available you receive AVERROR(EAGAIN) and you have to send more packets to the decoder (back to Step 1)

3.2) If frames are available you avcodec_receive_frame them until you get AVERROR(EAGAIN)